# Magento PayPal TLS v1.2 is cURL 7.29.0 ok or 7.34.0 required?

Tags: php, linux, magento, curl, paypal

Magento 1.9 is giving this warning:

***Your current version of cURL php5 module is 7.29.0, which can prevent services that require TLS v1.2 from working correctly. It is recommended to update your cURL php5 module to version 7.34.0 or higher.***

Does this mean that PayPal will break for sure after 30th of june or isn't that true? Because PayPal will be requiring TLS v1.2, but does cURL has to be 7.34.0 for that?

On SSL labs it's saying that the configuration supports TLS v1.2
[image: Test on https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html]

Answer (score 1):

If your Magento runs on CentOS / RHEL 7:

- You may be still get the warning despite having libcurl recent enough.
- Do *not* update libcurl from third-party repositories.
- Understand that libcurl package in RHEL may have an old version, but [include the fix already](https://www.getpagespeed.com/web-apps/magento/magento-paypal-libcurl-and-redhat-crazy-together).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, To avoid any disruption of service, you must verify that your systems
are ready for this change by `June 30, 2017`

> Why is PayPal making this change?

PayPal is upgrading all external endpoints used by merchants and partners to make programmatic connections. One of these changes is only allowing the use of HTTPS when connecting with PayPal systems to ensure that all information is securely transmitted. IPN messages contain sensitive information about your customers and their transactions that should only be passed securely.

> What are the upgraded security standards that PayPal is moving to for
>   all external endpoints?

PayPal is upgrading all of its external endpoints to the latest industry standards:

•   HTTP 1.1 or newer

•   HTTPS only

•   TLS 1.2 or newer only

•   2048-bit, SHA-256 certificates signed with VeriSign’s G5 root

> LibCurl

The source of the issue is your version of libcurl. libcurl versions earlier than 7.34 use TLS 1.1 or earlier by default.

To determine the version of libcurl you’re running, enter the following command on the server that processes PayPal transactions:

```
curl --version
```

If the version is earlier than 7.34, continue with the next section (solution). If you’re already running version 7.34 or later, no action is necessary.

> Check the solution [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements_tls1-2.html#solution)

Comment: Thanks for the reply and explaination. The server is ready for this, but as mentioned above Magento gives the warning about cURL lib version. But if I understand, this cURL lib version 7.34.0 is **NOT** required as long as the server supports the new standards, correct?

Comment: @Albert according to your warning. you libcurl version is less than `7.34` so you need to update it.

Answer (score -1):

If you still find yourself in need of an update you can try this link

https://www.mysterydata.com/update-install-latest-curl-version-on-rhel-8-rhel-7-centos-7-8-cwp-vestacp-cpanel-plesk/

Update Curl on RHEL 8 / CentOS 8 :

```
rpm -Uvh http://www.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/yum-repo/rhel8/x86_64/city-fan.org-release-2-1.rhel8.noarch.rpm
yum --enablerepo=city-fan.org install libcurl libcurl-devel
```

Update Curl on RHEL 7 / CentOS 7 :

```
rpm -Uvh http://www.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/yum-repo/rhel7/x86_64/city-fan.org-release-2-1.rhel7.noarch.rpm
yum --enablerepo=city-fan.org install libcurl libcurl-devel
```

Update Curl on RHEL 6 / CentOS 6 :

x86_64

```
rpm -Uvh http://www.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/yum-repo/rhel6/x86_64/city-fan.org-release-2-1.rhel6.noarch.rpm
yum --enablerepo=city-fan.org install libcurl libcurl-devel
```

i386

```
rpm -Uvh http://www.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/yum-repo/rhel6/i386/city-fan.org-release-2-1.rhel6.noarch.rpm
yum --enablerepo=city-fan.org install libcurl libcurl-devel
```